# Blazor state container singleton is creating multiple instances

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor popup (**avatar**), I'm trying to close it with a '*click anywhere to close*'

The toggle works, however calling **SetCloseAvatar** from the main layout **page**, I get a new instance with the default value of **true** when **CollapseAvatar** has already been set to **false** with the **Toggle**.

How injecting it in 2 different places does it become a separate instance?

> Note: Child component Avatar is a descendent of page, but not a direct
> child.

**Thanks for looking.**

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StateContainerService,StateContainerService>();
```

StateContainerService

```
public class StateContainerService
{
    public bool CollapseAvatar { get; set; } = true;
   
    public event Action ?OnStateChange;
   
    public void SetToggleAvatar()
    {
        CollapseAvatar = !CollapseAvatar;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }
    public void SetCloseAvatar()
    {
        CollapseAvatar = true;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }
  
    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnStateChange?.Invoke();
}
```

Avatar Component

```
private string? AvateCssClass => 
StateContainerService.CollapseAvatar ? "max-h-0" : "max-h-80 p-2";
private void ToggleAvatarView()
{
    StateContainerService.SetToggleAvatar();
  
}
```

MainLayout.Razor

```
<div class="page"  @onclick="@(()=>CloseAvatar("page"))" >
....stuff
</div>

private void CloseAvatar(string id)
{
  
    StateContainerService.SetCloseAvatar();
}
```

Comment: try `builder.Services.AddSingleton<StateContainerService>();`

Comment: What's missing is how you inject this class (2x).

Comment: Hi Henk StateContainerService.OnStateChange += StateHasChanged; was missing in OnInitializedAsync and 1 more thing i'll wait for an answer if anyone can see what else is missing